# How to implement autocomplete for cities with MapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I need to implement method which allows to receive list of cities (not full) by its first character. I thought I can use address autocompletion for this.

For example I can do it in Google APIs: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=V&types=(cities)&language=pt_BR&key=YOUR_API_KEY 
It returns 5 cities (because of types=cities) with "V" first character.

But I don't have such parameter in MapKit from Apple. If I use MKLocalSearchCompleter I only have

```
enum MKSearchCompletionFilterType : Int {
    case LocationsAndQueries
    case LocationsOnly
}
```

How I can resolve this problem and receive some cities by first character? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `MKLocalSearchCompleter` is a good way to go.

Based on `MKLocalSearchCompletion` results you can search for addresses from the results and perform a `MKLocalSearchRequest` along with `MKLocalSearch`. This will give you results that can be mapped to City entities which will be displayed as you wish.

Additionally, I've seen some methods based on comma separator in the title of `MKLocalSearchCompletion`, but as it is only a title for the search result you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: You're going to hit Apple's rate limiting almost instantly if you were to do this. This is not a viable solution for autocompletion.

Answer (score 0):

An `MKLocalSearchCompleter` object takes a partial search string and generates a list of potential completions. You use a search completer object to retrieve auto-complete suggestions for your own map-based search controls.

That's the class that uses https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/auto_complete.arpc

Its syntax is quite similar to the one of `MkLocalSearchRequest`:

```
MKLocalSearchCompleter.queryFragment = searchBar.text
MKLocalSearchCompleter.region = userlocation.region
```

But for results you will need to listen delegate methods:

```
(void)completerDidUpdateResults:(MKLocalSearchCompleter *)completer;
```

Comment: This provides no ability to limit the results to cities as the question specifies.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    var completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter?
    var searchResults = [MKLocalSearchCompletion]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        searchBar.delegate = self
        
        completer = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
        completer?.delegate = self
    }
    
    // MARK: - UISearchBarDelegate
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        completer?.queryFragment = searchText
    }
    
    // MARK: - MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate
    
    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        searchResults = completer.results
        // Update your UI to show autocomplete suggestions
        // For example, you can show suggestions in a table view
        // and reload the table view data
    }
    
    func completer(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // Handle autocomplete errors
    }
}
```